# Hibernate Property : hibernate.connection.autocommit

Tags: hibernate

I have not set this property in My Hibernate Configuration File and I was Using Postgres Database Connection using Hibernate Configuration.
But My transactions were executing fine but were not persisting in DB.
After setting this property 'COMMIT' the problem was resolve.
However when I used Jboss's PostgresDS file for DB connection without this property, all transactions were persisting and working fine..

Is this property is necessary ? 
(i think so -- because it solve my problem)
 but what are other consequences of this property?

Answer (score 0):

By default the autocommit value is false, therefore the transaction needs to be commited explicitly. This might be the reason why the changes not getting reflected in database, else can try `flush` to force the changes before commit.

When you close the session, then it will get commited in database implicitly [depends on the implementation].

When you have cascading transactions & needs to rollback for atomicity, you need to have control over transactions & in that case, autocommit should be false.

Either set autocommit as true or handle transactions explicitly.

Comment: My application was running for a whole day and i was able to get my updates (from session) all day, so does this mean session was not closed for the whole day.

Comment: @VikashTiwari As I said earlier, it depends on implementation, database etc. & without looking into code, it's difficult to comment.